# How to handle many different types of error for error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have a code that copy a workbook into a new one, keeping value only. In the workbook should have a named range "NotCopy" to indicate the number of sheets that will not be copied into the new file. The problem is that I run into at least 3 type of 1004 error.

- Sheet's name existed (when original file have sheet name like "Sheet1") `newSheet.Name = sh.Name` will throw error
- Could not found named range . `Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Names("NotCopy").RefersToRange` will throw error
- File with the same name is being open, the action of `.SaveAs` will get error.

If I use the code like below, it would not handle different error situations correctly. How do I do it?

```
Sub CopyWorkbookValue()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Output As Workbook, Source As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String
Dim OriginalName As String
Dim firstCell
Dim NotCopySheet As Integer
Dim r As Range

OriginalName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'Copy into no macro file only. Rename .xlsm into .xlsx
If Right(OriginalName, 1) = "m" Then
    OriginalName = Left(OriginalName, Len(OriginalName) - 1) & "x"
End If

Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Names("NotCopy").RefersToRange
NotCopySheet = r.Cells(1, 1).Value

StartCopying:
MsgBox "The number of sheet ignore is " & NotCopySheet
MsgBox "This macro cannot work with merged cell." & vbNewLine & "If there is merged cell, operation will not be completed successfully." & vbNewLine & "Remove all merged cell in ALL sheets before use"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook
Set Output = Workbooks.Add
'Set a unique name so it cannot be the same as the original file
Output.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet (0)"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As Integer

For Each sh In Source.Worksheets
    If sh.Index <= NotCopySheet Then
    Else

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    ' select all used cells in the source sheet:
    sh.Activate
    sh.UsedRange.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    ' create new destination sheet:
    Set newSheet = Output.Worksheets.Add(After:=Output.Worksheets(Output.Worksheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = sh.Name

    ' make sure the destination sheet is selected with the right cell:
    newSheet.Activate
    firstCell = sh.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Address
    newSheet.Range(firstCell).Select

    ' paste the values:
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next

' delete the empty sheet created when new book created.
If NotCopySheet = 0 Then
    Output.Sheets(1).Delete
End If

FileName = "C:\Dropbox\0 EPAS Export\ValueOnly_" & OriginalName
Output.SaveAs FileName
'Output.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    'MsgBox "Error number is " & Err.Number
    Select Case Err.Number   ' Evaluate error number.
        Case 1004   ' Range NotCopy not found
            NotCopySheet = 0
            MsgBox "Range NotCopy is not defined in this workbook, all sheet will be copied"
            GoTo StartCopying

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Something went wrong"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: These are all variations of the same problem: mishandling of objects.  This is not the kind of error for which you would add user-friendly error handling... instead, the problems with the code need to be addressed.  Perhaps instead of sharing the code for the error handling, you should share the code that is causing the error  (I suppose this is the very definition of "the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)".)  Also, see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.

Comment: I still couldn't imagine a way to address the problem without identifying the error, regardless of who is the one is supposed to fix it (user or developer). For example, if the sheet name already exist, it must be renamed. The code can do it, user can do it. But the code need to know the error is existing name to take the next action. Named range not found is not a pre-existing condition that can be identify before the code is run. I will edit and put in the full code so it's easier to analyse.

Comment: I think what @ashleedawg is getting at is that rather than waiting for the error to occur deal with it beforehand - use a custom function to check if the sheet or named range exists first before trying to reference it, check if the workbook is open before trying to open it.

Comment: I see what you mean... the "right way" to deal with that is to *test* thoroughly *before* releasing to the users...  that said, you remind me of a major project of my past, when i was developing  and implementing faster than Ii fully understood what i was coding and what affected what. I had Outlook send an email to my pager (shows how long ago) anytime any error occurred, often invisible to the user. Such as "1004" Object-errors.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: How do I check if a named range exist without using the error functionality. I am still a very beginner at VBA.

Comment: So to answrer your question there are a lot more than 3 ways to raise a 1004... thousands of possibilities. Error codes canr provide detail... if vba knew what wasgojng on then it woildnt have to error. What u did was have a log file that woukd log successful completion of each important line of code which makes it easy to look back and see what went wrong

Comment: The answers given by user6432984 _(the post on 16th rather than the accepted post on 18th)_ and DSVella in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410111/vba-named-range-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-name-exists) post give good examples.  You can then just add `IF NameExists(ActiveWorkbook.Names("NotCopy")) THEN....` to your code.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: Cool, how about checking if the target's file name is being opened?

Comment: At the top of your screen is a box with _Search_ in it - try typing _vba check if file is open_

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: sure

Comment: @ashleedawg Testing thoroughly before giving to the user is good advice regardless of the situation. What should be the case to use Error code then?

Comment: @ashleedawg After reflecting on this, I don't think it's an XY problem. It's clearly the limitation of Error class in VBA. The problem is Error class, not the implementation of it. At the end, the answer is do not use Error class, not re-identifying of problem.